# How can I retry a pool HTTP request based on certain status codes?

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-8, retry-logic

I'm making a set of HTTP requests using Laravel's Http::pool like so:

```
$responses = Http::pool(fn(Pool $pool) => $requests->map(fn($r) => 
            $pool->as($r->id)->myMacro()->post('myUrl', [
               ...
            ])
        ));
```

`myMacro()` is defined in `AppServiceProvider` like so:

```
        PendingRequest::macro('myMacro', function () {
            return PendingRequest::withHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => ...
            ]);
        });
```

I would like to amend `myMacro()` to set up a standard retry policy for the service I'm calling. I want to retry on both errors and certain HTTP status codes (e.g. 503).

I can't seem to get it to work, though. I tried calling `withMiddleware` in the macro to throw on certain status codes but the middleware was never invoked.

This feels like a straightforward ask; what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doing it, try to **change**:

```
    PendingRequest::macro('myMacro', function () {
        return PendingRequest::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => ...
        ]);
    });
```

**to this:**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Response;

PendingRequest::macro('myMacro', function () {
    return $this->withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => ...
    ])->retry(3, 100, function ($response, $e) {
        // Retry on server error status codes or exceptions
        return $e instanceof Exception || ($response instanceof Response && $response->status() === 503);
    });
});
```

Comment: Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest::retry(): Argument #2 ($sleep) must be of type int, Closure given

Comment: I tried this, but the callback function is never getting called on an error status code. Does this work for you?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion Yeah, what version of Laravel you are using ?